# Use ADAL to authenticate with office365 to manage word docs? from console app

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, office365

I want to know if it is possible to use office 365 API to interact with word documents in office 365 (create, update, and download). I have an azure directory setup, but I don't know how to leverage it to access the office 365 api to interact with these documents.

What is the process, if any, for using azure active directory combined with office 365 to manage documents? All of the resources I can find assume azure active directory will be used to handle authentication for a web service / web app. I wish to do this from a console app.

It is not necassary for me to use azure active directory, my only goal is to authenticate and interact with office 365 online word documents, so if there is someway to simply obtain a token directly through office 365 to manage word documents, that will solve my issue too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both ADAL or MSAL on a console based application and interact with Office documents using Graph API: The [OneDrive workload](https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/onedrive) in Graph API allows you to retrieve, download, upload documents from a OneDrive/ OneDrive for Business or SharePoint Document Library.

Below some resources/ samples that you can use as references:

- [GitHub Sample: Call the Azure AD Graph API from a native client (ADAL)](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console) - Sample application to show how to sign-in and query a Graph API in the context of the user and the application
- [Call Graph from Windows Desktop (MSAL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/guidedsetups/active-directory-windesktop) - A simple guide shows how to call a Graph API via REST on a .NET Desktop app - the same can be done with a console based app.
- [Service apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds) - Show more information on how to query AAD (using MSAL) on a context of an application (instead of a user).